# doInBackground() method in an AsyncTask doesn't work when the activity is being re-opened

Tags: android, android-asynctask, amazon-dynamodb

In my Android app, I have an activity which executes an `AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>` named `Scan` using this code: `new Scan().execute();`.

In the `onPreExecute()` method, it starts a progress dialog, on the `doInBackground(Void... voids)` method it scans a table from DynamoDB, and on the `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)` method, it dismisses the progress dialog, and views the results of the DB scan in a ListView using a custom `BaseAdapter` class.

When I open the activity, everything runs great, but when I press the back button, and enter the activity again, then only the `onPreExecute()` and the `onPostExecute(Void aVoid)` methods are being executed, while `doInBackground(Void... voids)` isn't being executed, so it just shows and dismisses the progress dialog, and nothing else is being viewed on the screen.

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
MessagesListAdapter messages;
ListView messagesLv;
public static ArrayList<Message> arrayList;
public static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public static DynamoDBScanExpression dbScanExpression;
public static List<Message> messageList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);

    new Scan().execute();
}

private class Scan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(name);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Searching for messages...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        dbScanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();

        Condition condition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(MainActivity.msgId));
        dbScanExpression.addFilterCondition("msgId", condition);

        messageList = MainActivity.mapper.scan(Message.class, dbScanExpression);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Message>();
        for (Message msg : messageList) {
            if (msg.getUserId() == null || msg.getUserId().equals(MainActivity.userId)) {
                msg.setMsgId(msg.getMsgId());
                msg.setDate(msg.getDate());
                msg.setTime(msg.getTime());
                msg.setMessage(msg.getMessage());
                msg.setUserId(msg.getUserId());
                arrayList.add(msg);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        if (!messageList.isEmpty()) {
            messagesLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesListView);
            messages = new MessagesListAdapter(MinaActivity.this, arrayList);
            messagesLv.setAdapter(messages);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noMessages);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code .

Comment: post the code..

Comment: `public static DynamoDBScanExpression dbScanExpression;`. That should be a local variable of doInBackground. And do not make it static!

Comment: Like your other variables. Dont make them public. Dont make them static. Make them local if possible.

Comment: @greenapps I changed it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Please edit your post so we can see the updates you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that it couldn't find any messages, was that I checked if the user ID of the message equals to the user ID of the registered user. The problem was that it was taken from `MainActivity.java` which got it from an Intent extra, therefore, when I have left the activity, the variable has been erased.

What I did is to refer to the user ID from the `SharedPreferences` and suddenly it worked.

Answer (score -1):

try to add `messages.notifyDataSetChanged();` in onPostExecute() method.

**or** use below code

```
    MessagesListAdapter messages;
ListView messagesLv;
public static ArrayList<Message> arrayList;
public static ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public static DynamoDBScanExpression dbScanExpression;
public static List<Message> messageList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_messages);
    messagesLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.messagesListView);
            messages = new MessagesListAdapter(MinaActivity.this, arrayList);
            messagesLv.setAdapter(messages);
    new Scan().execute();
}

private class Scan extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(TestActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setTitle(name);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Searching for messages...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        dbScanExpression = new DynamoDBScanExpression();

        Condition condition = new Condition()
                .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.EQ)
                .withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(MainActivity.msgId));
        dbScanExpression.addFilterCondition("msgId", condition);

        messageList = MainActivity.mapper.scan(Message.class, dbScanExpression);
        arrayList = new ArrayList<Message>();
        for (Message msg : messageList) {
            if (msg.getUserId() == null || msg.getUserId().equals(MainActivity.userId)) {
                msg.setMsgId(msg.getMsgId());
                msg.setDate(msg.getDate());
                msg.setTime(msg.getTime());
                msg.setMessage(msg.getMessage());
                msg.setUserId(msg.getUserId());
                arrayList.add(msg);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        if (!messageList.isEmpty()) {
           messages.notifyDataSetChanged();

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        } else {
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.noMessages);
            tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried adding it, but now it crashes when I enter it, because there is no data in the `MessagesListAdapter` at the beginning